# How can I tell which client process owns a particular Unix domain socket connection?

Tags: postgresql

I recently tried to call `ALTER TABLE`, which got blocked because one of the transactions holds a lock on the related table. With the help of #postgresql IRC channel, I managed to track down the problem to this particular process:d33tah

```
47329  0.9  0.0 275836 95384 ?        Ss   Mar03  23:59 postgres: d33tah projectname [local] idle in transaction
```

Still, I have no idea which **client process** owns this connection, so I cannot tell what it is doing. How can I debug that?

Comment: The process id (47329) is the column `pid` in the view `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: This does not tell me which process owns the connection.

Comment: Yes it does. The value of the column `pid` _is_ the process id in the operating system.

Comment: This is the backend PID. I would like to see which client spawned this process.

Comment: Again: you can see that in [pg_stat_activity](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) it shows the client IP address (together with the pid).

Comment: I cannot. This is a local connection and thus this provides no information to me.

Comment: Do you know what are the suspects?  Or who runs all those local processes/applications that open connections to Postgres?  And, I guess, there is no such thing something 'owns' a connection.  Even more, in the future you may want to set the `application_name` in the connection strings, so you can identify the culprit easier.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think the pid in the pg_stat_activity view lists the pid of the backend process on the database server machine, not the pid of the client process on the client machine; correct?

Comment: It doesn't concern me anymore, but I think that setting a unique application_name is a good solution for the next time. Also, combining  port information with `netstat` could possibly help.